# Block outgoing connections for certaing uids (root, apache, nobody)

Tags: centos, firewall, iptables, centos5, centos6

With iptables in CentOS 5 and 6 Linux - how can you please prevent processes running as **root**, **apache** or **nobody** from initiating outgoing connections?

On CentOS 5 Linux I've tried putting these lines into /etc/sysconfig/iptables:

```
-A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner root -j DROP
-A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner apache -j DROP
-A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner nobody -j DROP
```

but unfortunately get the error:

```
# sudo service iptables restart
iptables: Flushing firewall rules:                         [  OK  ]
iptables: Setting chains to policy ACCEPT: filter          [  OK  ]
iptables: Unloading modules:                               [  OK  ]
iptables: Applying firewall rules: iptables-restore v1.4.7: owner: Bad value for "--uid-owner" option: "apache"
Error occurred at line: 27
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.
                                                           [FAILED]
```

Comment: you can not do it using iptables. iptables only checks the ip packets , and there is no information about the uid / gid in there. iptables can only block packets by the source / destination fields, ports, ...

Comment: I know that OpenBSD's pf can do it. And also there seems to be the -m owner in Linux iptables too. So maybe you're wrong?

Comment: if I check my manpage, -m stands for match (module ) and not for the owner, maybe there is a module for the owner of the process, not sure.

Comment: In my understanding "-m owner" says to iptables: "please load the 'owner' module, so we can do things"

Comment: just checked, there is indeed a owner module. Never heard of it before. But it works with numeric id's, so he will have to alter his rule

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using the numeric UID instead of the name. For example:

```
-A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner 400 -j DROP
```

instead of

```
-A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner apache -j DROP
```

You can find the UID by typing

```
id user
```