# What's preventing the Apache user making outbound connections?

Tags: apache-2.2, networking, iptables, redhat, selinux

```
curl http://example.com
```

*data retrieved ok*

```
sudo -u apache curl http://example.com
```

*20 seconds later*

```
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

What would cause this, and how can I change it? I'm running some code as apache (mostly due to file permissions), and that code needs to be able to connect to another server.

Based on another question ([Block outgoing connections for certaing uids (root, apache, nobody)](https://serverfault.com/questions/376568/block-outgoing-connections-for-certaing-uids-root-apache-nobody)) I thought maybe the answer would be in /etc/iptables, but that file doesn't use -m owner:

```
# Firewall configuration written by system-config-firewall
# Manual customization of this file is not recommended.
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
```

SELinux is in permissive mode, as far as I can tell:

```
cat /selinux/enforce
0
```

What else could be causing this? RHEL 6.2.

Comment: Can it connect to other servers?

Comment: As far as I can tell, *I* can connect to any server, and Apache (the user) can't connect to anything at all, including other servers on the same network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, figured it out - it was a proxy issue. There was a proxy environment variable set in my start up scripts, that doesn't get called for apache.